# Why After implementing comparator in treeMap returning Values as null?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have Treemap which implements Comparator
if i print  this treemap object it is printing all  keys And values but when i am using for loop it is giving values as null
eg

```
     system.out.println(tm)

       for (Integer j : tm.keySet()) {

             System.out.println(j+" "+tm.get(j));

                }
```

**output is**
    {1=2, 1=3, 1=4}

```
1 null

1 null

1 null
```

full code is

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
 import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;
 import java.util.TreeSet;

 class com implements Comparator<Integer> {
    int day;

   @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    if (o1.intValue() >= o2.intValue()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
     }

   }

 class ChefStamph {

  static int adj[][];

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Integer>> days;
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    while (t-- > 0) {
        int n, m;
        n = sc.nextInt();
        m = sc.nextInt();
        adj = new int[m + 1][m + 1];
        days = new TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Integer>>();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {


            int day = sc.nextInt();
            com ob= new com();
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int b = sc.nextInt();

            if (days.containsKey(day)) {
                TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tm1 = days.get(day);
                tm1.put(a, b);

            } else {
                TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tm = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>          
           (new com());
                tm.put(a, b);
                days.put(day, tm);

            }

        }


        for (int i : days.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("for day :" + i);
            TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tm = days.get(i);
     /**//this print fine all keys and values**
            System.out.println(tm);
        for (Integer j : tm.values()) {
   ///**here i am geting  valus as null**
            System.out.println(j+" "+tm.get(j));

        }

        }
        System.out.println(days);

     }

   }

}
```

Comment: Your `Comparator` is inconsistent with `equals` without saying so. A `Comparator` inconsistent with `equals` _will_ give non-intuitive results when used in implementing, a `Set`/`Map`.

Comment: i wanted to store dublicate keys in treemap object that reason i used equal sign

Comment: You _should not want_ something not a `Map` in (a class extending) an implementation of `Map`. Fom the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html): `A _multimap_ is like a Map but it can map each key to multiple values. The Java Collections Framework doesn't include an interface for multimaps because …`. Several frameworks do provide them, e.g., Apache Commons Collections and google Guava.

Comment: The way to iterate the keys and values of a `Map` using `java.util` would be `for (Map.Entry kv: tm.entrySet())`, obviating all those look-ups.

Comment: how can i use apache implementation of multimap in online judge spoj or codechef?

Comment: I have no idea. This seems independent of `java.util.Map` implementation. I suggest asking about using non-Java-platform-resources on competition sites in general and Commons Collections on spoj or codechef in particular in a question of its own. Make sure to state what you found seeking this information on your own, ask in an appropriate forum/community, and follow the pertaining code of conduct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
       for (Integer j : tm.keySet()) {
           ....
```

This returns keys which you can pass to get(K key) method.

Comment: And I assume it fixed it, didn't it? Secondly also your Comparator implementation is wrong, it must return 0 if the parameters are equal. Although in this simple case it probably wouldn't happen...

Comment: i want to store dublicate keys in tm object that reason i have return 1..and my problem is still same

Comment: Well, I see. The reason is that the comparator never returns that the values are equals, i.e. it cannot find the value for any key you pass. The idea of getting multi value map with such comparator implementation is completely wrong and cannot work. Please check [Commons MultiValueMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html) - this should suite your needs better.

Comment: i added distinct keys in tm object still getting same answer

Comment: by the way i will upvote you because you tell me about new thing ( Commons MultiValueMap);

Comment: hey bro that was apache implementation how can it be used in online judge...i mean codehef ,hakerearth etc

Comment: You cannot get value even for distinct keys because your comparator never says the keys are equal (in other words does not return 0). Regarding online judge - I have no clue. But if that's needed, you can easily do this by creating map of integers mapped to collection: `TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` and then putting new value like this: `map.computeIfAbsent(key, (Integer key) -> { return new LinkedList<Integer>(); }).add(value)`